# VTDecompressionSessionCreate gives error -12911

Tags: h.264, rtsp, video-toolbox

I am using Video toolbox to decode H264 frames received via RTSP. Everything goes well, but after 5 days of usage (without restarting the phone) I get error -12911 when trying to create a new decompression session. It doesn't recover if I delete and reinstall the app, only if I restart my phone.

Did anyone experience this issue?

Comment: Did you find a solution?